# How to find connection string in Visual Studio Code

Tags: c#, database, oracle, connection-string

I am making my first web application (a one-page web application that shows four tables of sample data from my department in a hospital).

I am trying to make my connection string in my `web.config` file using this example:

```
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <configuration>
      <connectionStrings>
        <clear /> 
        <add name="name" 
        connectionString="server=localhost;database=myDb;uid=myUser;password=myPass;" />
      </connectionStrings>
    </configuration>
```

However, I do not know how to find the needed information (my Oracle database runs on a server, which is located elsewhere). I have found a good walkthrough to Visual Studio, where you can right-click on your connection in server explorer and then see your connection string in the properties section. This is not possible in Visual Studio Code, though.
So how do I find this information?

In Oracle SQL Developer I can find the following information: Name, hostname, port, service name. But which of these information should I use?

What is Add name? (is it the 'service name' I can see in SQL Developer?)
What is server? (is it the 'hostname' I can see in SQL Developer??)
What is database? (Is it Oracle?)

Comment: well you need the server IP address, port, and database name.  You need to ask your DBA

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have the IP address and the port - where in the xml script am I supposed to write this information? Is it server='IP adress'? And where should I write the port number?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at
[https://www.connectionstrings.com/oracle/](https://www.connectionstrings.com/oracle)

Maybe this will help you.
Usually if the port of the database server is not standard, it is sufficient to specify it with semicolons.

E.g. 10.100.1.200:1234

assuming 10.100.1.200 your server address and 1234 your server port.

You have to create a connection string like the one you have in your example. Just replace the needed informations (username, password, ip etc...)

Basically you should replace "localhost" in your connection string, with IP:PORT information (I think it should work)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).